# Text overflow even with vertical-align: top

Tags: css

If you take a look at this screenshot: http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/4350/photobenchmozillafirefo.png

You can see the text on the top right overflow the div. Eventhough I have placed `vertical-align: top` in there it still won't stick on the top. How do I make this text appear on the top?

Comment: margin? padding? line-height? absolut position? can you give more information pls! e.g. uploading the code anywhere

Comment: No, the code is very secret as you can see in the screenshot. :)

Comment: @Ispcity: `line-height` does not help, although you don't see that in the picture. Padding, margin or position is not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is at the top. Only the top for a font doesn't necessarily have to be the top visible pixel of a character. Trying to draw it even higher will force you to set the line height smaller than the font size, or set a negative margin. Both solutions may cause the text to be cut off on another computer and/or browser.

Comment: I was in the conscience that it has something to do with things you just explained, because it varies between fonts. So, is there nothing I can do about it other than changing a font or forcing it to the top using some ugly margin or padding tricks?

Comment: I'm afraid so. If you select text, the highlighted blue background shows you the actual font height. Doing that will tell you instantly if you have some unnotices padding or margins that you can strip. But that bar itself won't get smaller without tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `line-heigth` for the text.

Comment: I have tried it, but it makes no difference. A line height of 13px, a font size of 13px and a height of 13px and yet it still overflows.